# Can a decorator access variable type declaration in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to write a decorator like below, but to do that I need to somehow access the declared type. Is this possible?

```
def type_strict(fn):
  # some magic probably using inspect?

@type_strict
def example(a, b:int, c:str):
  #stuff

example("a", 2, "b") # ok
example(someRandomClass(), 2, "hi") # ok
example(someRandomClass(), "12", "by") # b should be int
example(someRandomClass(), 1, 214) # c should be str
```

Comment: Just access these "hints" via `__annotaions__` attribute of the function, i.e. `example.__annotations__` (or `func.__annotations__` if the function is a `func` argument of given decorator)

Comment: nice! thanks, the original question doesn't seem to have this detail

Comment: Yep, to be honest, I find the duplicate flag here as quite misleading for several other reasons...